# Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

I am using a serversfree.com account to learn joomla. The php version is 5.4

I get this error when I load my address http://kineteco.bugs3.com/

> Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL.

I have checked and rechecked the configuration file and everything about the database is correct

```
public $user = 'xxxxxxxxxx_keco';
public $password = 'xxxxxxxx';
public $db = 'xxxxxxxxxx_keco';
public $dbprefix = 'wa3fi_';
public $live_site = '';
public $secret = 'wR8kb4NfHikqN9a0';
public $gzip = '0';
public $error_reporting = 'default';
public $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help{major}{minor}:{keyref}';
public $ftp_host = 'ftp://ftp.kineteco.bugs3.com/';
public $ftp_port = '21';
public $ftp_user = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
public $ftp_pass = 'xxxxxxxx';
public $ftp_root = '/home/xxxxxxxxxx';
```

this is my first joomla website and I am already frustrated. Please help

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain the DB connection settings are correct, next ensure that you assigned the DB user to the database and assigned all privileges to the user.  This very simple miss has tripped me up before.

You generally do this in the same area of your hosting account where you established the creation of the database and user.  Now just assign the user to the db with all available permissions.

Comment: Thank you. it was a problem with the host name. For serversfree.com the hostname is 'mysql.serversfree.com' and not localhost. I learnt this just now. And amazingly my site works.